# Simple contact form snippet. Send mail to 2 email addresses

Tags: php

A client of mine has just asked me if it's possible to modify the following snippet to send an email to 2 different email addresses;

```
// Get Data 
$email = strip_tags($_POST['email']);

// Send Message
mail( "sampleemail@domain.com", "Holding page email submission",
"Email: $email",
"From: Hold Page <$email>" );
```

I didn't write the code so I'm not really sure how to do it.

Any ideas?

Comment: separate the mails with a coma? or calling the `mail()` with different id's twice if you don't want the users to get the email of other users in the list when they receive mails?

Comment: I strongly recommend using a decent mailer class for sending mails with PHP, such as PHPMailer or Swiftmailer.

Comment: There are a ton of solutions to this, have a quick google and you'll find the answer in no time :)

Answer (score 0):

[PHP mail](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php)

The 'to' field takes Receiver, or receivers of the mail so you can provide two emails there.